# Imageresizing return negatif image

Tags: imageresizer

I use imageresizer (v3) since 3 years now on an heavy image website (Real Estate) with non problem. I update to version 4 and now I have some problem. When a resize, some image output in negative style. [image]

Here are my configuration:

```
<resizer>
<image404 default="~/404/default.png" chaletfr="~/404/fr_chalet.png" condofr="~/404/fr_condo.png" maisonfr="~/404/fr_maison.png" terrainfr="~/404/fr_terrain.png" locationfr="~/404/fr_location.png" chaleten="~/404/en_chalet.png" condoen="~/404/en_condo.png" maisonen="~/404/en_maison.png" terrainen="~/404/en_terrain.png" locationen="~/404/en_location.png"/>
<!-- Presets plugin Config -->
<presets onlyAllowPresets="false">
  <preset name="thumbnail" defaults="width=61;height=45;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="small" defaults="width=115;height=80;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="medium" defaults="width=195;height=131;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="large" defaults="width=275;height=184;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="big" defaults="width=437;height=289;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="envedette" defaults="width=147;height=102;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="thumbac" defaults="width=75;height=50;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="propsem" defaults="width=341;height=252;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="constvedettephoto" defaults="width=259;height=173;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="constvedettelogo" defaults="width=86;height=25;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="mobilelist" defaults="width=150;height=150;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="mobiledetail" defaults="width=414;height=310;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="semaine" defaults="width=465;height=345;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="extralarge" defaults="width=300;height=225;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="xxlarge" defaults="width=400;height=300;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="extrabig" defaults="width=600;height=450;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
  <preset name="extrathumbnail" defaults="width=95;height=70;scale=canvas;mode=crop;bgcolor=dee4ed;"/>
</presets>
<!-- ClientCache Config -->
<clientcache minutes="525600"/>
<!-- RegExFriendlyUrlPlugin Config -->
<RegExFriendlyUrlPlugin regex="^(?&lt;langue&gt;fr|en)(_(?&lt;type&gt;[A-Za-z]+))*_(?&lt;preset&gt;[A-Za-z]+)_(?&lt;id&gt;[0-9]+)(_d(?&lt;hash&gt;[0-9]+))*\.(?&lt;extension&gt;jpg|png|gif)"/>
<!-- SizeLimiting Config -->
<sizelimits imageWidth="0" imageHeight="0" totalWidth="8000" totalHeight="8000" totalBehavior="throwexception"/>
<!-- DiskCache Config -->
<diskCache dir="~/cache" autoClean="true" hashModifiedDate="true" enabled="true" subfolders="32" cacheAccessTimeout="15000" asyncWrites="true" asyncBufferSize="10485760"/>
<cleanupStrategy startupDelay="00:05" minDelay="00:00:20" maxDelay="00:05" optimalWorkSegmentLength="00:00:04" targetItemsPerFolder="400" maximumItemsPerFolder="1000" avoidRemovalIfCreatedWithin="24:00" avoidRemovalIfUsedWithin="4.00:00" prohibitRemovalIfUsedWithin="00:05" prohibitRemovalIfCreatedWithin="00:10"/>
<pipeline defaultCommands="fastscale=true"/>
<plugins>
  <add name="Reference.ImageResizerPlugins.MySqlReader.MySqlReaderPlugin" connectionString="server="" prefix="~/" idType="UInt32" blobQuery="" modifiedQuery="" existsQuery="" requireImageExtension="false" extensionPartOfId="false" untrustedData="true"/>
  <add name="Reference.ImageResizerPlugins.RegExFriendlyUrl.RegExFriendlyUrlPlugin"/>
  <add name="FolderResizeSyntax"/>
  <add name="Image404"/>
  <add name="Presets"/>
  <add name="DiskCache"/>
  <add name="PrettyGifs"/>
  <add name="SimpleFilters"/>
  <add name="FastScaling"/>
</plugins>
```

Is there someone who already have this problem?

Thanks

Comment: This bug has been fixed, but is currently on the nightly release feed only.

Comment: Did you know when the release will be? If a nuget package will be deploy?

Comment: You can get it now via https://www.myget.org/F/imazen-nightlies/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Nathanael Jones say it's have been fix in the nightly build and we can download it via myget.org/F/imazen-nightlies